# NSXMLParser Separate Three Elements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, itunes, nsxmlparser

I am parsing an xml file with three of the same elements: "im:imageLink". Currently I am adding all three links to an array:

```
if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"im:image"]) {   
    string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    [imageLinks addObject:string];
}
```

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me how I could separate each of the three elements, and put them in three different arrays.

Comment: Why do they need to be in three separate arrays?  What is the structure of the XML?

Comment: They are all different sizes. One of the links is:http://itunes.apple.com/GB/rss/topsongs/limit=50/genre=20/xml. I am getting all of the data from <entry> and as you can probably see there are three of the same element "im:image".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the comments above, you want to separate the items by the height attribute, which seems to come in 3 known values: 55, 60, and 170. In this case, you could split them based on the attribute dictionary passed in to the parser:didStartElement:... call. Presuming you called the attributes variable "attributeDict", your call would look something like:

```
int height = [[attributeDict valueForKey:@"height"] intValue];
```

From there you can use a typical if...then...else construction to stuff the results into the three different arrays. Like:

```
if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"im:image"]) {   
    string = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    int height = [[attributeDict valueForKey:@"height"] intValue];
    if (55 == height) {[imageLinks55 addObject:string];}
    else if (60 == height) {[imageLinks60 addObject:string];}
    else if (170 == height) {[imageLinks170 addObject:string];}
    else {NSLog(@"Unrecognized height of an image!");}
}
```

Comment: didnt see your post so I did this before anyway! Thanks a lot!.